# Telerik's RadDataGrid cell content textbox binding for UWP

Tags: uwp, grid, prism

We have used DataGridTemplateColumn for our grid to display texbox for a column. via Prism MVVM, We've a requirement to update other column in the grid if the textbox value has been changed. 
ex. I have 3 columns in my RadDataGrid, when I updated data1 column, 
data3 column will be auto updated (data1 textbox value + data2 value).

Thanks for the help ~

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid
x:Name="DataGrid"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.DataList,Mode=TwoWay}">
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data1" >
                            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Data1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Data2" PropertyName="Data2" CanUserResize="False"/>                            
<telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Data3" PropertyName="Data3" CanUserResize="False"/>
```

Comment: it's work for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ex. I have 3 columns in my RadDataGrid, when I updated data1 column, data3 column will be auto updated (data1 textbox value + data2 value).

For your requirement, you could create `Item` class that contain `Data1` `Data2` `Data3` three properties like the follow.

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _data1;

    public string Data1
    {
        get
        {
            return _data1;
        }
        set
        {
            _data1 = value;

            this.Data3 = Data1 + Data2;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string _data2;

    public string Data2
    {
        get
        {
            return _data2;
        }
        set
        {
            _data2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _data3;

    public string Data3
    {
        get
        {
           return _data1 + _data2;
        }
        set
        {
            _data3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The point is you need modify the value `Data3` in Data1's `set` method. And when you modify Data1' value by typing some words, the `Data3` will be changed automatically.

And this is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App8/tree/master/App8) that you could refer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's work for me.

Comment: hello, one more question is how can I get the notice if one item's data2 has changed in an ObservableCollection<Item> collection ? because of data1 and data2 and data3 were int type, so there is a total amount of data2 field in my viewmodel, for now data3 will be auto updated by data2 updated. but how to re-calculate total data2 amount ? thanks